# Сайт отображается на чужом домене

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, dns, vds

Заметил, что мой сайт полностью скопирован на другом домене. Информация вся обновляется в реальном времени. При попытке определить IP домена - выдает ip моего домена.
Подскажите, на что обратить внимание, чтобы решить проблему ? Может DNS как-то неверно заполнены или конфиг Nginx ?

Comment: В настройках nginx запретить обработку неизвестных доменов, например сделав default_server с return 444 внутри

Comment: у меня прописано `listen 11.222.333.444:443 ssl default_server; ` но это не помогает .

Comment: Ну а запрет запросов внутри этого default_server прописали?

Comment: подскажите, как правильно это прописать, не могу сообразить

Comment: добавил 

`if ($host != "sait.ru") {
      return 444;
     }`

Не знаю, насколько правильно так делать будет, но сработало

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого домена на своем сервере создавайте отдельный блок server и явно указывайте server_name